# Relative path to a gif image breaks when appended to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Question Background:**

I have a form on a view that will display a loading 'spinner' gif when a users submits this form.

**The Issue:**

If I include the spinner `img` element within its holding div then the spinner is rendered, but this is then obviously shown all the time which I do not want:

[image]

If I append the `img` element to the spinner using jQuery when the form is submitted then the relative path cannot render the spinner:

[image]

**Code:**

This is the div hat the spinner `img` element will be appended to.

```
<div id="loadSpinner" class="text-center">
</div>
```

jQuery used to append the img elemtn with the realtive path to the spinner gif.

```
    function showSpinner() {

    var spinner = '<img src="~/Images/LoadingSpinner.gif">';

    $(spinner).appendTo('#loadSpinner');

}
```

Any helping determing why this will not render would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are mixing razor code that doesn't get run in the dom.

**`~`** is not part of valid http url path. Use proper path to image

Try just removing `~` assuming `Images` directory is in root of the site

```
var spinner = '<img src="/Images/LoadingSpinner.gif">';
```